# How can i get two minipage environments to print on the same line?

Tags: latex

I'm trying to use the minipage environment in latex so that i can write some equations on the left and on the right of tha page and then frame them. But when i insert the equations, the next minipage environment skips a line for some reason. Does anyone know how to solve this so that both environments print on the same line ?
Here's the code that i use :

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{4cm}
\centering
$\lambda \log E^* = 1,8792$\\
$1 - \lambda = 0,819$
\end{minipage}

\begin{minipage}[c]{4cm}
\centering
$E^* = 32354,44$\\
$\lambda = 18,1\%$
\end{minipage}
```

Answer (score 1):

The empty line between your minipages indicates a new paragraph and consequently will put the second `minipage` in a new line. So the solution is simple: don't add an empty line

```
\begin{minipage}[c]{4cm}
\centering
$\lambda \log E^* = 1,8792$\\
$1 - \lambda = 0,819$
\end{minipage}
%
\begin{minipage}[c]{4cm}
\centering
$E^* = 32354,44$\\
$\lambda = 18,1\%$
\end{minipage}
```